# Apache Spark DAGScheduler Flow of Data

Tags: apache-spark, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am trying to understand how exactly Apache Spark scheduler works. To do so, i've set a local cluster with one master and two workers. I only submit one application, which simply reads 4 files (2 small (~10MB) and 2 big(~1,1GB)),joins them and collects the result. In addition, i cache in memory the two small files.

I am running the standalone cluster mode with FIFO.I've understood how the stages are formed but i cannot figure out how the flow of data is determined(the arrows). When i look at SparkUI, i notice that each time,even though the stages are formed in the same way, the arrows( flow of data and control i guess) are different. It's like the scheduler works non-deterministically.

I've read the relative chapters (about DAG and Task Scheduler) from Jacek Laskowski's book, but it isn't still clear in my head how the flow of control is determined . Thanks in advance for the help.

Cheers,

Jim

Comment: It's only now when I noticed you referenced my gitbook! :) Thanks. If there's anything more unclear, keep us posted.

Answer (score 1):

> It's like the scheduler works non-deterministically.

Yes, there's some randomness in scheduling tasks to make it more "fair". In that sense Spark scheduler does work "non-deterministically", but within acceptable limits of execution placement (i.e. assigning tasks with lesser location preferences to executors).

The component in Apache Spark that does the work of selecting a task for a task set (that corresponds to a stage) is [TaskSetManager](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/TaskSetManager.scala):

> Schedules the tasks within a single TaskSet in the TaskSchedulerImpl. This class keeps track of each task, retries tasks if they fail (up to a limited number of times), and handles locality-aware scheduling for this TaskSet via delay scheduling. The main interfaces to it are resourceOffer, which asks the TaskSet whether it wants to run a task on one node, and statusUpdate, which tells it that one of its tasks changed state (e.g. finished).